# Error when trying to copy xlsx file path into R

Tags: r, xlsx

I am trying to import a xlsx file into R but I keep getting this error when copying the file path. The file path is "C:\Users\aj\Downloads" so I have been writing:

> library(openxlsx)

> Data <- read.xlsx(paste0(C:\Users\aj\Downloads, '\Data.xlsx'))

I tried switching to "/" from "" and I got a different error that stated unexpected input. Does anybody know what I am missing or if I am even on the right track?

Comment: Have you set all the text in the `paste0` function in inverted commas? `paste0("C:\Users\aj\Downloads", "\Data.xlsx")`

Comment: Have you tried double back-slash `Data <- read.xlsx('C:\\Users\\aj\\Downloads\\Data.xlsx')`? The back-slash often works as an escape-character.

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around: you could use the Import Dataset button in the Environment pane. It will import the dataset for you and also show you the correct command.